# How can I trigger this function from the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I have this Javascript on my homepage which opens a popup.

I need a way to create a URL which then opens the popup immediately.

I've read on other posts that I need to use parameters and then add something like ?parameter=true to the url. The problem is I don't know javascript.

Can anyone help me with adding parameters to my js code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#customButton").click(function () { $("#crazyrocket-launch-icon").trigger("click") });
});
```

Comment: have you managed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `searchParams.Get()` to grab the value of the parameter from the URL. You can then run your function on `document ready` after checking with an `if statement`.

```
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?popup=true";
var url = new URL(url_string);
var popup = url.searchParams.get("popup");

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (popup) {
    $("#crazyrocket-launch-icon").trigger("click");
  }
});
```